# Java KeyEvent confusion

Tags: java, regex, awt, jtextfield, keyevent

I have a program which is a mock inventory system with quite a few `JTextField`'s and some regular expressions which some of those fields must comply with. Also, some fields cannot be null(obviously) or an empty String. In order to assist the user to input data, I've added some `ImageIcon`'s to show if the input data is valid or invalid. (a green check or red x) and I `setVisibility()` as the user types via KeyEvents.

With that said, here is the confusion. I have a block which I'm pretty sure doesn't have a bug in it, but I've found that there's some odd things happening:

I'm only calling my `updateIcons()` method in response to `keyTyped()` - my overrides for the others are empty. Now, when a key is typed, the text is printed on the screen before the key is released, so you would think that an input field that simply requires at least one character to NEVER fail the validity check because if `keyTyped()` is the only entry point to my `updateIcons()` method, there should always be at least one character by the time the key is released and thus registered as a "key typed". However, it seems to be firing an event before the key even gets registered to the System. Something which makes this even more odd is if I call my `updateIcons()` method twice in a row from the overridden `keyTyped()` method, the program STILL fails the check for empty string. BUT if I call it for `keyPressed()`, `keyReleased()`, and `keyTyped()` all for the same event, presto; valid data. Could this possibly be caused by the instability/bugginess of AWT?

Here is the updateIcons() method in case it is something I overlooked, but since I'm getting such odd results I don't think its a bug on my end.

```
//called from keyTyped
//formInputIcons is a 2D array[8][2] where the first dimension represents
//the form input field, and the second dimension is the ImageIcons for that field
//public final Pattern upcRegex = Pattern.compile("^\\d{12}$");
//public final Pattern anyNumRegex = Pattern.compile("^\\d+$"); 

public void updateIcons(KeyEvent e){

    if(e.getSource() == formAddInputs[0]){
        formInputIcons[0][0].setVisible( ! (upcRegex.matcher(
                ((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText()).matches()));
        formInputIcons[0][1].setVisible(upcRegex.matcher(
                ((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText()).matches());

    }else if(e.getSource() == formAddInputs[1]){
        formInputIcons[1][0].setVisible(((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText().equals(""));
        formInputIcons[1][1].setVisible( ! ((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText().equals(""));

    }else if(e.getSource() == formAddInputs[3]){
        formInputIcons[3][0].setVisible(((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText().equals(""));
        formInputIcons[3][1].setVisible( ! ((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText().equals(""));


    }else if(e.getSource() == formAddInputs[4]){
        formInputIcons[4][0].setVisible(((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText().equals(""));
        formInputIcons[4][1].setVisible( ! ((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText().equals(""));


    }else if(e.getSource() == formAddInputs[6]){
        formInputIcons[6][0].setVisible( ! (anyNumRegex.matcher(
                ((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText()).matches()));
        formInputIcons[6][1].setVisible(anyNumRegex.matcher(
                ((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText()).matches());


    }else if(e.getSource() == formAddInputs[7]){
        formInputIcons[7][0].setVisible( ! (anyNumRegex.matcher(
                ((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText()).matches()));
        formInputIcons[7][1].setVisible(anyNumRegex.matcher(
                ((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText()).matches());
     }
}
```

UPDATE: I'm an idiot - it works fine if I only call `updateIcons()` once from `keyReleased()` and leave `keyPressed()` and `keyTyped()` empty. I like to learn things though; could someone explain why `keyTyped()` is buggy in this usage but `keyReleased()` works fine or post a link please?

Comment: you have to use DocumentFilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be calling your update method from `keyReleased()`.  I've made a simple `JTextField` which outputs the key and its `getText()` each time a key is pressed, and watch what happens:

```
keyPressed:c
text:
keyTyped:c
text:
keyReleased:c
text:c

keyPressed:a
text:c
keyTyped:a
text:c
keyReleased:a
text:ca

keyPressed:t
text:ca
keyTyped:t
text:ca
keyReleased:t
text:cat
```

You can see that the actual text of the `JTextField` is not updated by the `keyTyped()` or `keyPressed()` events.